# Getting error on npm start while starting local host server in React.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, react-scripts

Getting this error on npm start

> 'Equipment' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\Home\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

[image]

Comment: Please, don't include code as image but prefer copy/paste :)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem by changing the name of parent folder of my app.

Previously it contained spaces therefore it was showing

> 'not recognized as an internal or external command'

error.